# How can I assign the click event handler as I click the row in QT?

Tags: qt, qtgui, qtsql

I know how to bind the QSqlTableModel and QTableView to display all the data in the specific table in the databases. Here, it's my code.

```
QSqlTableModel model;
QTableView *view1 = createView(&model, QObject::tr("Table Model (View 1)"));
view1->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

If I need to jump the other form as I click the ith-row on the view, how do I assign the click event?

For example, If I click the 3rd rows, I will jump to the user form to show the 3rd user info.

Comment: What do you mean by another form..?
You mean some other widget.>?
Can you add some code to show that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtain the QItemSelectionModel from by calling QTableView::selectionModel(). Connect to the signal QSelectionModel::selectionChanged(QItemSelection const&, QItemSelection const&). In your slot, you can examine the change of selection the determine what has been clicked on.